# Slow Loading of Google Sheets Formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I keep getting the Error -> Loading Data with =importXML. It keeps loading, even after hours of not touching the document, its still loading.

Its a file with 500 - 750 + =importXML formulas as well as lots of others.

Can we change anything to actually load in the data?

Example file: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q-gDH9xGtzIespfEt2fEcFdpD_m9HTCtqXNkXmNfR2U/edit#gid=1748917714)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Last I knew, the limitations for all `IMPORT` functions was 50 per spreadsheet. So you are far exceeding that. You may need to set up separate spreadsheets that each include no more than 50 IMPORTXML calls, then combine that data into one spreadsheet using an IMPORTRANGE stacked array. In addition, if you are using individual cell formulas ("drag-down" method), it's quite possible that hundreds or thousands of such formulas can be condensed into one well-written array formula per column (or even per multiple columns). As player0 invites, share a link for a more detailed assessment.

Comment: It would be great, I will prepare an Example Sheet for you ASAP and get back to you.

Comment: There you go @ErikTyler [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q-gDH9xGtzIespfEt2fEcFdpD_m9HTCtqXNkXmNfR2U/edit#gid=1748917714)

Comment: Your overall intent for the spreadsheet is not clear given the number of cells that are returning errors. However, I can tell you that you are, in fact, using hundreds of formulas where a few would do the same job more efficiently in many places. In addition, as I think you know, you are using IMPORT-type functions excessively.

Comment: There *may* be ways to approach and achieve your goal, but your current approach is filled with problems from start to finish. In my opinion (and I've been at this a long time), there is no way to "fix" what you've built here. It would need to be entirely rebuilt. And building or rebuilding systems from the ground up goes far beyond what this free, volunteer-run forum is designed to provide (which is advice and small help on single formulas or lines of script that are already almost correct). I'm sorry to deliver bad news, but it's best to know the truth.

Answer (score 0):

According to the large number of importxml native functions, I would recommend getting the source step by step (url after url) by script and retrieving the info using regexextract

```
function importSource(url='https://www.amazon.nl/s?k=Flexi') {
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  // apply regex or split to getch the information
}
```

By doing so, you will control how the information is downloaded.